# C# Custom Attribute Alternatives

Tags: c#

Currently, I've created a class with ~30 properties to be set. This is done to build up a URL request later on(ie, "http://www.domain.com/test.htm?var1=a&var2=b...&var30=dd").

The issue I'm facing is the property names don't necessarily match the query variable names(this is intended to be different). For example, I may have a variable titled "BillAddress", whereas the query variable will need to be "as_billaddress".

I have no control over the query variable naming scheme as these are set at an external source.

One possible solution I've used is creating a custom attribute and decorating the properties with their respective query counterparts:

```
[CustomQueryAttribute("as_billaddress")]
string BillAddress{get;set;}
```

To retrieve the attribute though, requires a little reflection and due to the larger number of properties, I was curious if there is a neater way to accomplish this functionality. Not so much as setting/retrieving custom attributes without reflection, but being able to tie an alternate string variable to any property.

I've also pondered about setting each variable up as a sort of KeyValuePair, with each key representing the query counterpart, but I didn't get too far in that thought.

To summarize/clarify my above backstory, what would you do to associate a string with a property(not the value of the property)?

As always, any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but something to think about.. From your example, it looks like you're passing sensitive data in The querystring... Surely you're not passing billing info from page to page this way, are you?

Comment: Excellent question Dave. No, I'm not actually passing anything sensitive page to page here. This actually touches a rating API which just needs a locale to return a set of quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably stick with a custom attribute, but the other potential option would be to do something like hold a static Dictionary that had string and property info (or property name), so you could get/set the property directly via this.

Something like:

```
static Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> propertyMap = new Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>();

static MyClass()
{
     Type myClass = typeof(MyClass);
     // For each property you want to support:
     propertyMap.Add("as_billaddress", MyClass.GetProperty("BillAddress"));
     // ...
}
```

You could then just do a dictionary lookup instead of using reflection in each call...  This could also be setup fairly easy using configuration, so you could reconfigure the mappings at runtime.

Comment: All comments on the question have been very helpful. Mostly hit me as a sanity check, but the dictionary approach is very attractive.

Answer (score 1):

A custom attribute seems like the best option to me - the framework seems to do this a lot as well (specifically with serialization).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at popular ORM mappers then nearly all either use custom attributes or some kind of XML mapping file. The advantage of the latter is that you can modify the mapping without recompiling your application - the downside is that it hurts performance. However, I'd say your choice seems perfectly reasonable.